# Xcode and iOS9's "Asset packs must be in /OnDemandResources" error

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, on-demand-resources

I updated to iOS 9 GM and Xcode 7 GM and am in the process of submitting an update to my game.

However, the validation process now comes up with an "Asset packs must be in /OnDemandResources." error.

[image]

Here's the log

> 2015-09-14 18:50:52 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items
>   with error: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Unexpected
>   asset pack at
>   /Applications/churningseas.app/AssetPacks/Dropbox.assetpack. Asset
>   packs must be in /OnDemandResources."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected asset pack at
>   /Applications/churningseas.app/AssetPacks/Dropbox.assetpack. Asset
>   packs must be in /OnDemandResources.}
>
> 2015-09-14 18:50:52 +0000 [MT]
>   Presenting: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Unexpected
>   asset pack at
>   /Applications/churningseas.app/AssetPacks/Dropbox.assetpack. Asset
>   packs must be in /OnDemandResources."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected asset pack at
>   /Applications/churningseas.app/AssetPacks/Dropbox.assetpack. Asset
>   packs must be in /OnDemandResources.}

And here is my Xcode directory, showing the Assetpacks are currently under Ressources (I went a little crazy with blurring, sorry about that):

[image]

I guess this is due to Apple's new "app thinning" system, which I'm not particularly wanting to use right now for a small update.

Is there a way to disable on-demand resources? If not, how to fix this (do I simply need to move my "Assetpacks" folder to another one called "OnDemandResources")? I so, where? I'm a little nervous to mess up my file structure...

Also, I did already look at the assets section of the build setting, and "Enable on-demand resources" was already set to "no"

[image]

any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have become an issue since iOS 9 introduced on demand resources. The terms "AssetPacks" or "assetpack" inside folder references cause an error when attempting to validate an archive.

Because this seems to effect Codea-exported projects under version 2.3.1 and earlier. Here is a fix specifically for a Codea exported project:

- Find the file named `libversion` in the root of your exported project. It will contain a version number, most likely `2.3.1`. Change it to `2.3.2`
- Delete `libcodea.a` and `libtools.a` from your `Libs/` folder
- Delete the "AssetPacks" folder reference from the "Resources" group in your exported Xcode project — if Xcode asks you to move the files to trash say NO.
- In Finder: rename the "AssetPacks" folder to "Assets"
- In Finder: Rename every "SomePack.assetpack" folder within it to "SomePack.assets"
- Drag the root level "Assets" folder back into Xcode, tell Xcode to add this as a "Folder Reference" (not a "Group")

There's a more in-depth discussion here https://bitbucket.org/TwoLivesLeft/core/issues/366/trying-to-export-xcode-file-so-i-can#comment-22075482

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure this out but I seem to have gotten something that works. Once you archive your build, if you go to XCode's preferences and click on the tab Location, you will find the location of the archive saved files. If you then click the link just under the Archives section, it will bring you to a folder (which you open) that contains the archives in it. Navigate to the date on which you archived the build and then (using get info to determine time) locate your build. Right click on it and then click "Show Package Contents". Then click on Products. Make a new folder called "OnDemandResources". Click on Applications and right click on the file and open the package contents. Depending on the previous locations of your assets they will be somewhere there, but for me they were in a handy folder titled Assets. Once you have found the folder containing your assets you need to copy it and delete it. Inside the OnDemandResources folder we created earlier, make a new folder called what ever your package bundle identifier is (com.------.-----) and add to the end of it: .New.assetpack . Then paste your AssetPacks (or Assets) file inside. Now you to create a new text edit file, set it to plain text, and then type: bplist00“TTags_CFBundleIdentifier°SNew_?com.Identifier.Identifier.asset-pack-00000008CM2Z9
')-o
This is what it says for mine, I don't know if it will work for you, but I don't see why not. 
This method worked for me and now I have a working .ipa file. I hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I'll try it tomorrow. I do hope it works, but it seems mad we have to do that every time we want to submit a build! :D Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I few questions @Hugo Selvesta: what should the text file be called? should it be saved in the new folder with the bundle id? Also, this might sound dumb, but how do I get an ipa from this (I did the change in the xcarchive folder, which indeed contains an ipa, but not only)?

Here's what my folder looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnp1ne3y7svvsn5/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-09-19%2010.08.57.png?dl=0

Thanks!